# Wordpress contact form 7 post variables

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to build upon a contact form 7 plugin to pass the inputs as `$_POST` into a second page upon submit. Google has proved rather fruitless with this. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this/where I can find a solution?

Thanks in advance

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-3rd-party-integration/

But if you prefer to do it manually - basically this is the hook you should use: wpcf7_before_send_mail